# will gcc optimize switch on a constant variable

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement, constants, compiler-optimization

as for the following pure c code:

```c
typedef enum eFoo_t
{
  FOO_ONE,
  FOO_TWO
} eFoo;

typedef struct Foo_s
{
  const eFoo x;
  int (*f) (const eFoo x);
  int (*g) (struct Foo_s *y);
} Foo;

int G(Foo *y)
{
  switch (y->x)
  {
    case FOO_ONE:
    return 1;
    case FOO_TWO:
    return 2;
    default:
    break;
  }
  const eFoo z = y->x;
  switch (z)
  {
    case FOO_ONE:
    return 1;
    case FOO_TWO:
    return 2;
    default:
    break;
  }
}

int F(const eFoo x)
{
 switch (x)
  {
    case FOO_ONE:
    return 1;
    case FOO_TWO:
    return 2;
    default:
    break;
  }
}

int main()
{
  const eFoo x = FOO_ONE;
  Foo y = {.x = FOO_TWO, .f = F, .g = G};

  F(x);    // Q1: will the switch be optimized out
  F(y.x);  // Q2: will the switch be optimized out
  y.f(x);  // Q3: will the switch be optimized out
  y.g(&y);   // Q4: will the first and second switch be optimize out
  
  return (F(x) + F(y.x) + y.f(x) + y.g(&y); // 
}
```

trying to find out if there is some benefit when switch on a const variable.
I think this kind of optimization should be reasonable and easy to be implemented.
as in the comment, gcc -O1 directly returned 6 in https://godbolt.org.

Answer (score 1):

As to whether `gcc` *does* optimise it, I couldn't say, your best bet would be to enter it into https://godbolt.org and see.

But it *could.* It probably doesn't even need to be `const`. If the compiler can figure out it never has any value other than the one, it's free to optimise it out.

The standard mandates visible behaviour, not underlying methods, this is what's known as the "as if" rule. Provided an implementation acts "as if" it followed the standard, it's following the standard, and can do it in any manner it sees fit :-)

However, I suspect not in this case (at least not within the `F` and `G` functions themselves, though it could probably inline the function behaviour within `main` and optimise it there). That's because they can be called from outside on this translation unit, meaning they won't *know* that they'll always be called with a constant value (either `const` or unchanging).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I have checked https://godbolt.org/, -O1 already optimized all the cases. the main function directly returned 6 as I change the code to `return (F(x) + F(y.x) + y.f(x) + y.g(&y);`
so `const` is only useful for a code maintenance purpose rather than a optimize purpose.
as it is really annoying to declare a const  member in a struct, for initialization. xd

Comment: `main: mov eax, 6 ret` @paxdiablo you are correct, without `const`, the `switch` still optimized out.